# How to use prefetch_related on nested serializer related objects in django rest framework?

Tags: django-rest-framework, query-optimization, django-serializer

From the model below i'm trying to return the count for the different course types for particular university on the course serializer with lesser number of queries as possible.

> Model

```py
class University(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['name']
        verbose_name_plural = 'Universities'

    def __str__(self):
        return "%s" % self.name



class CourseType(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField("Course Name", max_length=255)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Course(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField("Course Name", max_length=255)
    course_type = models.ForeignKey(
        CourseType,
        null=True,
        blank=True,
        related_name='course_type',
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    university = models.ForeignKey(
        University,
        null=True,
        blank=True,
        related_name='courses',
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL
    )

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

> Serializer

```py
class UniversitySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    course_type_count = serializers.SerializerMethodField(
        'get_course_type_count')

    class Meta:
        model = University
        fields = "__all__"

    def get_course_type_count(self, obj):
        course_count = {}

        # This one is causing extra query
        courses_type = obj.courses.all().values('course_type__name').annotate(
            total=Count('id')).order_by('course_type')
        for course_type in courses_type:
            course_count[f"{course_type['course_type__name']}"] = course_type['total']
        return course_count


class CourseSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    course_type = serializers.CharField(source='course_type.name')
    university = UniversitySerializer(read_only=True)

    @staticmethod
    def setup_eager_execution(qs):
        qs = qs.select_related('university')
        qs = qs.select_related('course_type')

        # This is what i've tried
        qs = qs.prefetch_related(
            Prefetch('university__courses__course_type',
                     queryset=qs.prefetch_related('course_type'))
        )


        return qs

    class Meta:
        model = Course
        fields = "__all__"
```

> What i've tried.

On the course serializer i'm **prefetching the CourseType** as:

```py
qs = qs.prefetch_related(
        Prefetch('university__courses__course_type',
                   queryset=qs.prefetch_related('course_type'))
    )
```

In the above ORM call, i'm prefetching course type and iterating through the objects. as below on `UniversitySerializer`

```py
courses_type = obj.courses.all().values('course_type__name').annotate(
   total=Count('id')).order_by('course_type')
```

Still there's a duplicate query in the debug toolbar.

Answer (score 1):

One thing that you should be aware is that `prefetch_related` is working as long as you access `.all()` or the queryset that matches the `Prefetch` object queryset. In your case the `get_course_type_count` does an annotate to calculate a count, thus prefetch objects cannot be used. What I suggest is to do the count calculation in python.

```
from collections import defaultdict


class UniversitySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    ...

    def get_course_type_count(self, obj):
        course_count = defaultdict(int)

        for course in obj.courses.all():
            course_count[course.course_type.name] += 1

        return course_count
```

It should be enough to just use this prefetch

```
qs = qs.prefetch_related(
    Prefetch('university__courses__course_type')
)
```